# Rails 4, Bootstrap and f.radio_button

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, bootstrap-sass

I am creating a standard form in rails but I am using sass-bootstrap to present a more good-looking interface.

My question extends to use of bootstrap labeling of a f.radio_button input. Below is the code I am using.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <%= f.label :activity %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :activity, "Load/Unload", :id=>"Load/Unload" , :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="Load/Unload" class="btn btn-primary">Load/Unload</label>

  <%= f.radio_button :activity, "Begin shift", :id=>"Begin shift" , :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="Begin shift" class="btn btn-primary">Begin shift</label>

  <%= f.radio_button :activity, "Complete shift", :id=>"Complete shift", :style=>"display:none;" %>
  <label for="Complete shift" class="btn btn-primary">Complete shift</label>
</div>
```

Now this looks good and works (on click the selected button goes into active display) until I click the submit button. At this point the selected input is not added to the form and the :activity variable is left blank.

If I remove the div class="btn-group"... lines clicking on the buttons works for inputting data but the visual button change does not occur.

Any ideas on why this would occur? Should I use jquery to facilitate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I kind of resolved a similar issue using the following code that works:

```
     <%= f.label "Select Network type:", :class=>"control-label input-group" %>
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <%= f.radio_button :network_type, false %>Optical
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <%= f.radio_button :network_type, true, :checked=>"checked" %>IP&Optical
        </label>
      </div>
```

I still have to replace the internal labels but it works just fine. Try it